# how to use some eloquent method and then one time use get() and one time use paginate()

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to use this

```
$user = User::where('name','john');
```

then first time

```
$all = $user->get();
```

second time

```
$paginate = $user->paginate(10)
```

I know I can do like this :

```
$user = User::where('name','john')->get();
$user2 = User::where('name','john')->paginate(10);
```

but I want only one time call

```
User::where('name','john')
```

what should I do ?

Comment: After `$user = User::where('name','john');`, `$user` is a query builder. you can reuse it as much as you want. have you tried that ?

Comment: There isn't much reason to do that with the code you posted. Any attempt to "reuse" that `where()` clause would end up longer than and just as efficient as the way you have it typed currently. Can you expand on _why_ you want to do this a bit more?

Comment: If you are doing this for optimization purposes, know that it won't change anything since the database calls will happen on the `get()` and on the `paginate()`, so it will still run two distinct database queries.

Answer (score 1):

Store the query as a variable and then use it to populate two sets of results.

```php
$query = User::where('name', 'john');

$users = $query->get();
$paginatedUsers = $query->paginate();
```